# Scala generic upper bound

Tags: scala, generic-programming

I'm trying to write a simple utility

```
def withParLevel[T, Col <: ParIterable[T]](coll: Col, ts: TaskSupport): Col = {
  coll.tasksupport = ts
  coll
} 
withParLevel(List(1,2,3,4,5).par, blockingPool)
```

Which gives me this error:

```
inferred type arguments [Nothing,scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int]] do not conform to method withParLevel's type parameter bounds [T,Col <: scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[T]]
```

How can I fix that?

Why does it infer T to Nothing, not to Int?

PS scala version 2.10.2

Comment: Curious, I'm not sure why the type inference fails here. I'll wait for someone to explain that. In the meantime, changing it to a wildcard (`[T <: ParIterable[_]]`) or a view bound (`[A, B <% ParIterable[A]]`) seems to work...

Comment: I'd drop the `Col` type param completely and use subtyping polymoprhism: `def withParLevel[T](coll: ParIterable[T]): ParIterable[T] = coll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type bound to View Bound. Scala compiler needs evidence between the two type parameters that Col => scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[T]

Let's have a quick REPL session: (For compilation I did not use the TaskSupport param)

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable
import scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable

scala> def withParLevel[T, Col <: ParIterable[T]](coll: Col): Col = coll 
withParLevel: [T, Col <: scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[T]](coll: Col)Col
```

Let's fix the compilation error using View Bounds:

```
scala> def withParLevel[T, Col <% ParIterable[T]](coll: Col): Col = coll
withParLevel: [T, Col](coll: Col)(implicit evidence$1: Col => scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[T])Col

scala> withParLevel(List(1,2,3,4,5).par)
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int] = ParVector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Edit: 
Reason: If one of the type bounds drives the other (in your case, Col derives the inference from T), you would need View Bounds.

Comment: Seems to work, but it is unclear why type bound not working. So general rule: If you want some complex types use '<%' instead of '<:'